# How to make PHP flush() work on Azure web apps?

Tags: php, azure, web, flush

This simple script will run without a problem on a LAMP server (Ubuntu) running on a VM/Azure. However, when ported to Azure web apps (php), the same script will get a `502` or `504` error after 5 minutes, and will show no output. If the number of lines is reduced to less than 300 (about 5 minutes time) it will run, but all lines will appear only when the script ends.
Any thoughts?

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
for($i=0;$i<600;$i++)
{
    echo 'printing...'.$i."<br>";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you should add a `\n` or PHP_EOL to the echo.

Comment: If you don’t get data during the processing then it means that you are behind a reverse proxy which is certainly there to protect the backend against attacks and to be able to cache data if your web app sends HTTP headers regarding *Cache-Control*. Some reverse proxies do handle a kind of « pipe » mode to just shuffle bytes between the client and the backend but this has to be configured. I would try and read about that if Azure has this piece of software in front of your PHP. Typically I had this case with a PHP script transferring big files. I had *Varnish* in front but managed a VCL conf.

Comment: thanks Markus, but EOL did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Iwasa found the solution and posted it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/578408/how-to-make-php-flush-work-on-azure-web-apps.html?childToView=578568#answer-578568
The issue was caused by my decision to use PHP 8.0. This will cause Nginx to be used instead of Apache (in Azure web apps - PHP).
Just replacing PHP 8 by 7.4 solved the problem both the 5 minute timeout and the flush() not working.
Hope this helps somebody else!